# Jupyter Notebook can't even work properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

For some reason, I can't even run this basic line. It should just accept this, but it won't even do that. Every time I open Jupyter Notebook, something like this has to happen. And of course, there isn't really any way to permanently fix it. There hasn't been much that I can try, but messing around with Jupyter has also screwed up my other IDEs.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np

import nsfg
import first


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-58d7125e1e68> in <module>
      1 from __future__ import print_function, division
      2 
----> 3 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      4 
      5 import numpy as np

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2315                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2316             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2317                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2318             return result
   2319 

</Users/hedyeherfani/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-108> in matplotlib(self, line)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in matplotlib(self, line)
     97             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
     98         else:
---> 99             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui.lower() if isinstance(args.gui, str) else args.gui)
    100             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    101 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   3417                 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)
   3418 
-> 3419         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
   3420         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)
   3421 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in activate_matplotlib(backend)
    318     # when this function runs.
    319     # So avoid needing matplotlib attribute-lookup to access pyplot.
--> 320     from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    321 
    322     plt.switch_backend(backend)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>
     30 from cycler import cycler
     31 import matplotlib
---> 32 import matplotlib.colorbar
     33 import matplotlib.image
     34 from matplotlib import rcsetup, style

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in <module>
     25 
     26 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 27 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     28 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     29 import matplotlib.collections as collections

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in <module>
     12 from . import cbook, docstring, rcParams
     13 from .path import Path
---> 14 from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, Transform, TransformedBbox,
     15                          TransformedPatchPath, TransformedPath)
     16 

ImportError: cannot import name 'Bbox' from 'matplotlib.transforms' (/Users/hedyeherfani/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py)
```

Comment: Maybe your matplotlib  is broken, I suggest you reinstall it.

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a very old version of matplotlib. For example, [version 0.91.2](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v0.91.2/lib/matplotlib/transforms.py) doesn't have class Bbox in transforms.py, but most newer versions do.

- To confirm this, open the referenced file, /Users/hedyeherfani/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py,  and check for `class Bbox(BboxBase)` or something similar (a symbol called Bbox needs to be defined)
- Evaluate `import matplotlib; matplotlib.__version__` into a Python interpreter to determine your version of matplotlib.
- Upgrade by using a command such as `pip install matplotlib==<newversion> --upgrade`

Comment: It says there is no newer version, and running the import matplotlib matplotlib._version_ returns nothing

Comment: What is saying there is no newer version? You need two underscores around "version", so make sure it is `__version__`, not just `_version_`. Even https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v0.91.2/setup.py#L264 Or you can use `pip list|grep matplotlib` to try to get the version in another way. Not sure what system you are using.